# Eureka Client register with multiple Eureka server issue

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka

In my case want to register one microservice with multiple Eureka server from different zone.
I have tried with putting:
defaultZone: http://192.168.207.24:9002/eureka/,http://192.168.207.24:9003/eureka/ 
but in this case eureka client is getting registered with second one not on both.